# How does catkin tell if a dependency is a system or ROS dependency?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get dependency tracking in our package.xml files squared away, but ROS seems to be trying to treat libeigen3-dev as a ROS package rather than a system dependency.

Specifically, I've got a package that depends on Eigen, the well-known header-only linear algebra library.  Sounds like a build dependency, so:

```
<build_depend>libeigen3-dev</build_depend>
<export_build_depend>libeigen3-dev</export_build_depend>
```

Here's what happens when I run rosdep check:

```
    ~/sentry_dev_ws$ rosdep check --from-paths src --ignore-src
All system dependencies have been satisified
ERROR[ds_sim]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libeigen3-dev]
    rosdep key : libeigen3-dev
    OS name    : ubuntu
    OS version : xenial
    Data: no data
```

Changing the dependency name to "eigen" fixes this, but eigen isn't an ubuntu apt package name.  I have the same issue with google protobuf, and will probably have it again in the future.

I have a suspician catkin's packaging tools will prove very poweful.  Just gotta figure them out first.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283423/how-does-catkin-tell-if-a-dependency-is-a-system-or-ros-dependency?/) by [ivaughn](https://answers.ros.org/users/32451/ivaughn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep key for Eigen is: `eigen`. Put that in the build depend.

On Ubuntu it resolves to the **libeigen3-dev** package. On other operating systems it may resolve to some different package name.

Similarly, `protobuf` resolves to **libprotobuf9v5** on Ubuntu Xenial.

For a general introduction to rosdep: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/rosdep

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
A bit of a 'plug', but some more info on `rosdep`, keys and why we use those: #q215059 (and perhaps #q217475).

**Comment by [ivaughn](https://answers.ros.org/users/32451/ivaughn/) on 2018-02-27**:
That's all great, the logic makes sense, etc.  But the rosdep tutorial linked does not solve the problem I have.

If I have a library key, with an apt package name, how do I find the rosdep key to put there?  And if it doesn't exist, how do I create it.  For my local system, that ships next week.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-27**:
I'm not sure a reverse `rosdep` lookup tool exists, but I could just have missed it.

As a work-around, open [ros/rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/base.yaml), `ctrl+f` and type in the name of your deb pkg. If there are no hits, follow the procedure ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-27**:
.. to submit new rules [here](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html).

Personally I skip the *Make sure that your rules work* section most of the time.